# Dimension and the number of coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Why is that the number of coordinates has to be greater than the dimension of a given vector space?

Say there is a linear transformation $\textsf{T}:\textsf{V}\to\textsf{W}$ and $\textrm{dim}(\textsf{V})=2, \textrm{dim}(\textsf{W})=3.$ So I have to use at least $3$ coordinates to describe both vector space?

When I read $\beta_{\textsf{V}}=\{v_1,v_2\}$, which is a basis of $\textsf{V}$ and that's ok for me to understand: it's a linearly independent subset of $\textsf{V}$ which spanning $\textsf{V}$. But it becomes quite confusing when you say $\beta_{\textsf{V}}=\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$. Why use three? not four, five, ...coordinates?

It seems like there is an observer which in a higher dimension to describe the linear transformation?

Comment: Where is it mentioned that $\beta_V = \{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$? If $V$ is a $2$-dimensional vector space, you don't need to use $3$ coordinates for it unless it's a subspace of a $3$-D vector space.

Comment: In general $\textsf{T}:\textsf{V}\subseteq \mathbb{R^m}\to\textsf{W}\subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$ thus T maps m-dimensional vector in n-dimensional vector but we have that $0\le \dim(V) \le m$ and $0\le \dim(W) \le n$.

Comment: This is the outset of all my questions about $F^n$ that followed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, in general, if $V\subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$ any element of V is an $n$- dimensional vector but dim(V) can be between $0$ and $n$ depending on the number of vectors in a basis for $V$. You should distinguish the two concepts.